# In VMware Workstation is there a way to directly connect the wireless NIC to the Kali Linux virtual machine?

Tags: kali-linux, vmware

I'm new to Kali Linux.

I'm running Kali Linux inside VMware Workstation.

I have a Ralink USB wireless NIC connected to my PC.

I want to enable Monitor mode which is simply done with the *airmon-ng start wlan0* command.
But there's no wlan0 adapter to be found. When I enter the *ifconfig* command I only see eth0 and lo:
[image]

Comment: This isn't really a security question, even if you're using Kali, but a VMWare networking question. Probably a better fit on Superuser

Comment: Sorry. Can you move it?

Comment: Did you actually connect the USB NIC to the VM?